# Asp.net 5 compilation process using dnvm

Tags: asp.net-core, jit, coreclr

Can anyone please explain me how the compilation and execution of Asp.net5 application works in detail.

I'm Completely new to .net environment

Couple of questions 
when you build application using VS 2015 (press F5), steps involved  that i know are

- Code gets converted to CIL. (what is its name ? is it Rosyln Compiler
  )
- This CIL code is interpreted to machine code

Now what happens when i run application using dnvm ,

```
  1. how is it compiled ?
  2. What does CoreClr do?
  3. how is CoreClr different from Clr
  4. What happens when we do dnu restore
  5. what happens when we do dnx . exe
  6. At what stage is the CIL generated , where is the CIL stored 
  7. At what stage the JIT is used?
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First of all, [DNVM](https://github.com/aspnet/dnvm) is not used for compiling nor running your app. DNVM is an acronym for DotNet Version Manager and is used for managing different .NET version. You can for example have one app that uses [.NET Core](https://github.com/dotnet/core#net-core-platform) and another app that uses the full .NET Framework. The former is the cloud optimized, cross-platform version of the latter and which lets you deploy the runtime together with your app. Read more [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/12/04/introducing-net-core.aspx) about the differences.

1. How is it compiled? On Windows ["Roslyn"](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn) is used to compile your app. On Linux/Mac, [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/) is currently used but will be replaced with Roslyn once it's supported on those platforms.
2. What does CoreCLR do? [CoreCLR](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr) is the runtime for .NET Core.
3. How is CoreCLR different from CLR? CoreCLR is the runtime for .NET Core and CLR is the runtime for the .NET Framework.
4. What happens when we do [dnu restore](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-utility#restore-dnu-restore)? Your apps' dependencies are downloaded and added to the packages directory.
5. What happens when we do [dnx . exe](https://github.com/aspnet/Home/wiki/DNX-structure#dnx-usage)? It will look for the project.json file in the current folder (denoted by the dot) and invoke the 'exe' command as configured in the project.json file.
6. At what stage is the CIL generated , where is the CIL stored? CIL is generated when compiling. When you do `dnx . run` for example the app is built in memory. If you on the other hand do `dnu build`, it will produce assemblies (e.g. dll:s) for your app in which the CIL is stored.
7. At what stage is the JIT used? JIT stands for Just-In-Time compilation and is performed when the application is executed. It translates the CIL code to native platform specific code.

You can find more information in the [ASP.NET 5 documentation](http://docs.asp.net/en/latest/) (work in progress).

Comment: Thanks @davidfowl! :)